# Make extra delete votes affected by beta privilege scaling

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, vote-to-delete, beta-sites

Currently, you gain the privilege to delete questions on beta sites at 2000 reputation, starting out with 5 delete votes per day.

You gain 1 additional delete vote for every 1.000 reputation past that, so to cap off your deletion votes, you need 27.000 reputation on a beta site and 35.000 reputation on a graduated site.

I think the scaling is off. You get the deletion privilege for 5x less reputation on beta sites, why not affect the delete vote scaling the same way?

I suggest to reduce the scaling proportionally to what the privilege is reduced to, so you'd get an extra delete vote every 200 rep past 2.000.

It's a tad inconsequential to have Beta privilege unlocks cap out at 5.000, except for delete votes which cap out at 27.000, while on graduated sites, the capping of delete votes at 35.000 fits in neatly with after the 20.000 and 25.000 milestones. I think having it at 200 per extra vote (resulting in the maximum 30 deletion votes at 7.000 reputation for beta sites) would make it fit in neatly with the 4.000 and 5.000 milestones there.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate here: On which beta site did you (and how many others) daily run-out of delete votes?

Comment: @rene I ran out today on IPS and I already have a list of things I want to DV next.

Comment: @Magisch - What does downvoting something have to do with voting to delete it?